# What is the Ramda equivalent of this Lodash uniqBy call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

```
const data = [
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1001]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1002]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000, 1003]},
{id: "002", failedReason: [1000]}
];
```

Given this data set if I wanted to return an array of objects with unique `id` values only then I could use Lodash to simply call:
`_.uniqBy(data, 'id')`

I know that with this method only the first occurrence of an element/match is kept.

The above would return:

```
[ { id: '001', failedReason: [ 1000 ] },
  { id: '002', failedReason: [ 1000 ] } ]
```

I'm brand new to Ramda. What is the Ramda one- liner equivalent to this?

`R.uniqBy(???, data)`

Comment: I know nothing about Ramda, but looking [at the documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#uniqBy) it appears you need a function that takes each element returns the id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ramda doesn't do the lodash style of allowing a string to serve as an alternative for a function to get the named property of an object.  So just pass a function:

```js
const data = [
  {id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
  {id: "001", failedReason: [1001]},
  {id: "001", failedReason: [1002]},
  {id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
  {id: "001", failedReason: [1000, 1003]},
  {id: "002", failedReason: [1000]}
];

console.log(uniqBy(prop('id'), data))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {uniqBy, prop} = ramda    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return the `id` of each element:

```js
const data = [
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1001]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1002]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000, 1003]},
{id: "002", failedReason: [1000]}
];
const res = R.uniqBy(({ id }) => id, data);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use the Ramda `prop` function:

```js
const data = [
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1001]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1002]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000]},
{id: "001", failedReason: [1000, 1003]},
{id: "002", failedReason: [1000]}
];
const res = R.uniqBy(R.prop("id"), data);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```